# How to set up a Remote Docker Registry behind a firewall (WAF)?

Tags: artifactory

We have the JFrog Artifactory set up behind an enterprise firewall (Fortigate WAF). The FortiGate is using certificate for authentication.

The CI pipeline put the images on GCR, and we want to use the Artifactory Remote Docker registry to proxy the image into the on-prem zone.

When we set up Artifactory proxies, there's only user name and password option for authentication to proxy, how to set up the proxy to use certificate for authentication?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to follow the below steps to add the certificate for authentication purposes. (Assuming your Artifactory version is 7.x)

1. Navigate to UI --> Administration --> Services | Artifactory --> Security | Certificates
   [image]
2. Add the pem file in the [certificate](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Security#ArtifactorySecurity-Certificates) with an alias name to it.
3. Add the certificate details in the repository's [SSL/TLS certificate section](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Advanced+Settings#AdvancedSettings-RemoteCredentials) in the basic tab
   [image]
   The authentication via certificate should happen without issues.